# nonetype object has no attribute text error while scraping data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

when i try to scrap data from this [amazon link](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=laptops&sprefix=%2Caps%2C634&ref=nb_sb_ss_recent_3_0_recent). I got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

**My Code:**

```
headers = ({'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
       'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5'})
lap_site = requests.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?k=laptops&sprefix=%2Caps%2C634&ref=nb_sb_ss_recent_3_0_recent',headers = headers)
lap_soup = bs(lap_site.content,'lxml')
content = lap_soup.find('div',class_ = 's-desktop-width-max s-desktop-content s-opposite-dir sg-row')
lap_detail_block = content.find_all('div',class_ = 'a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small')
lap_name = lap_price = lap_rating = []
for i in lap_detail_block:

   laptop_name = i.find('h2').a.span.text
   lap_name.append(laptop_name)

   laptop_rating = i.find('span',class_ = 'a-icon-alt').text
   lap_rating.append(laptop_rating)

   laptop_price = i.find('span',class_ = 'a-price-whole').text   
   lap_price.append(laptop_price)

laptop_details = {
'Laptop':lap_name,
'Price':lap_price,
'Rating':lap_rating }

print(laptop_details)
```

I think that the `laptop_rating` variable store the content in string format even if we not include `.text`. I'm thinking that might be the reason for getting `NoneType` error, as we are extracting text from text. Anyway that's not the issue. How to extract the price or rating from that link?

Comment: This basically means that your *not* getting the HTML source code *you think* you should be getting. In other words, there's no element that contains the price.

Comment: Try printing out `lap_soup`, see what it says: is it mentioning something about 'automated access'?

Comment: At the moment, for debugging purposes, try using the try-except on the code block inside your for loop. i.e., try: ........ except AttributeError: ...... then check if you have a result. If not, then most likely the problem is with the find method arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least from my tests, that page is recognizing automated access and blocks it. You need to use something like `cloudscraper` to do it. The following code will return the expected results (adapt to your own circumstances):

```
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

r = scraper.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?k=laptops&sprefix=%2Caps%2C634&ref=nb_sb_ss_recent_3_0_recent')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
# print(soup)
content = soup.find('div',class_ = 's-desktop-width-max s-desktop-content s-opposite-dir sg-row')
lap_detail_block = content.find_all('div',class_ = 'a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small')
lap_name = lap_price = lap_rating = []
for i in lap_detail_block:
    try:
       laptop_name = i.find('h2').a.span.text
       lap_name.append(laptop_name)

       laptop_rating = i.find('span',class_ = 'a-icon-alt').text
       lap_rating.append(laptop_rating)

       laptop_price = i.find('span',class_ = 'a-price-whole').text   
       lap_price.append(laptop_price)

       laptop_details = {
        'Laptop':lap_name,
        'Price':lap_price,
        'Rating':lap_rating 
       }
       print(laptop_name, laptop_rating, laptop_price)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print('_____________')
```

This will print out in terminal:

```
HP 15s, 12th Gen Intel Core i5 8GB RAM/512GB SSD 15.6-inch(39.6 cm) FHD,Micro-Edge, Anti- Glare Display/Win 11/Intel Iris Xe Graphics/Dual Speakers/Alexa/Backlit KB/MSO/Fast Charge, 15s- fq5111TU 4.2 out of 5 stars 58,699
_____________
Acer Predator Helios 500 Gaming Laptop (11Th Gen Intel Core I9/17.3 Inches 4K Uhd Display/64Gb Ddr4 Ram/2Tb Ssd/1Tb HDD/RTX 3080 Graphics/Windows 10 Home/Per Key RGB Backlit Keyboard) Ph517-52 3.0 out of 5 stars 3,79,990
_____________
ASUS VivoBook 14 (2021), 14-inch (35.56 cm) HD, Intel Core i3-1005G1 10th Gen, Thin and Light Laptop (8GB/1TB HDD/Windows 11/Integrated Graphics/Grey/1.6 kg), X415JA-BV301W 3.8 out of 5 stars 27,990
_____________
[...]
```

Cloudscraper's details and install instructions: https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/